# What is the origin of "in one fell swoop"?

Tags: phrase-origin

I know the meaning, but wanted to know the origin of the phrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fell_swoop) says it originated in Shakespeare's *MacBeth*:

> Ro. Wife, Children, Seruants, all that could be found. […]
>   Macd. […] All my pretty ones?
>   Did you ſay All? Oh Hell-Kite! All?
>   What, All my pretty Chickens, and their Damme
>   At one **fell swoope**?

Comment: [This is a good explanation, too.](http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/one-fell-swoop)

Comment: As an anti-link rot measure: @JLG's link explains that "fell" in this context means "fierce" or "deadly" and the "fell swoop" is the way a bird of prey plunges from the sky to kill its prey.

Comment: i think of LOTR and maybe a Nazgul. fell indeed!